# How to convert the pandas series to a dataframe that is shown in the attached figure?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, arraylist, series

[Here I want to convert [] square bracket values to Dataframe...but I can not convert it. Please give a solution of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIT2G.png)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show what is type of element of series? using this type(f.iloc[0])

Comment: Yes...this is the file

0    [-0.032146886, -0.017225446, 0.00074751483, -0...

1    [-0.036141224, -0.021889636, 0.0021449307, -0....

2    [-0.033587664, -0.023399109, -0.00056308386, -...

3    [-0.0353535, -0.0058738324, 0.0037062576, -0.0...

Name: 2, dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this input [Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
series = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
```

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
dtype: object
```

To convert the list to rows, use [`pandas.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
series.explode()
```

```
0    1
0    2
0    3
1    4
1    5
1    6
dtype: object
```

To convert the list to columns, use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) + [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html):

```
series.apply(pd.Series)
```

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got my solution.